# Multiple Tabs with Different Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I am pretty new to Android. I am making a new App which makes use of Tabs.
Now, I want to display different fragments in the tabs.

**Please note that my MinSDK is Android KitKat 4.4 so I wont be using deprecated methods**

My Code is:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.search)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You tapped on SEARCH !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).


        return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);

        Button b1 = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
}
```

Fragment_Main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter your Name (Fragment Main"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et1"
    android:hint="Enter your ID (Fragment Main)"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment_1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity$FragmentOne">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/et2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**I have changed the tools:context in fragment_1.xml for my tests. I don't know what it does
Now, when the user opens the App, he should see the Fragment_Main fragment. When he swipes for the next tab, he should see fragment_1.**

Please help in detail as i am very new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what exactly doesn't work?

I can only guess, but you don't use Fragment_Main.xml anywhere.
You are already passing position of view pager to your fragment, you should retrieve it and inflate layout based on it. Something like this inside your fragment:

```
private int mFragmentIndex = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mFragmentIndex = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

and in onCreateView you should inflate different layout based on fragment index:

```
    View rootView;
    if (mFragmentIndex == 1) {
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.Fragment_Main, container, false);
    } else {
         rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }
```

Anyway, I would suggest using different fragments, instead of inflating different layouts. Something like this:

```
 @Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return MainFragment.newInstance();
    } else {
        return SomeOtherFragment.newInstance();
    }

}
```

Comment: can you make those changes and put in my code please? i dont get where to put it.

Comment: @AdhishThite they go inside SectionsPagerAdapter

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sver. Just one more simple question. I want to add a title to each tab. I dont find a way to do it. Please help.

Comment: @AdhishThite inside SectionsPagerAdapter there is getPageTitle method where you get title for each tab.

Comment: Yes there is. I even made changes there. But I cannot see the titles to the tabs in my Application. Please help. I am a newbie.

Comment: Oh, I notice you don't have tabs. Check this manual about adding them > http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#tabs

Comment: If those are not Tabs, then what are they ? What am I doing ?

Comment: Also, the methods used in the link you sent me are deprecated.

Comment: Those are not tabs. They are fragments in View Pager. You can swipe between them, but there is no actual tabs at top. Unless you are developing for only for Lolipop you could still use that method. If you dont want to, you could try using library like https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip